# Which is correct, "The car is at the station" or "The car is in the station"?

Tags: grammar

I was answering this question when another question (I mean the titled question) entered my mind

Did you park your car ... the station? (The answer was "at")

I'm a little bit confused now. I thought the best choice is the preposition "in".

Comment: I parked my car **at** the station, **in** the car park.

Comment: You don't drive a car inside a railway station, do you? You leave it outside and walk in to wait for your train.

Comment: @KateBunting Who said train station? It could be a gas station, or a service station.

Comment: Normally "station" refers to a railway station. You can of course park **in** the petrol/gas station's **carpark**. But not every petrol/gas station has this facility whereas I'm pretty certain that every railway station has a carpark (UK) or parking lot (US).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many stations: railway stations, fire stations, gas stations. I will presume you meant fire station since that is *obviously* what most people think about.

1. Did you park your car at the station?

That means "in the parking lot", or maybe on the street nearby.

2. Did you park your car in the station?

That means, did you drive your car into the building where the fire engines are.

Both choices are valid.

In your imagination, if you tend to mean "in the parking lot", then you'd usually say "at the station".

Comment: `I will presume you meant fire station since that is obviously what most people think about.` Really? A fire station?  My first thought was a railway station. Do  civilians park their car at a parking lot that is reserved for employees? Sarcasm??